# OpenCV displaying avi file encoded in I420

Tags: c++, video, opencv, avi

I am trying to write a video processing application using OpenCV 2.4.2 (in Visual C++ 2010 Express on Windows 7) but I am having trouble displaying certain AVI files. Most display correctly, but when I use an AVI file encoded in I420 format all I get is a striped pink image for every frame (it displays correctly in regular media players).

Output displayed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f15hM.png

Currently, I am using the C++ API, but the same thing happens when I use the C API (code from this page: http://nashruddin.com/how_to_play_avi_files_with_opencv). I find this strange, because in most answers on this site and resources on the web, they explicitly recommend to use the I420 encoding. Does anyone know what could be causing this or how to fix it?

Here is a trimmed down version of the code I am using:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
string fname = "test.avi";
VideoCapture capture(fname);
if(!capture.isOpened()){
    cerr << "error opening " << fname << endl;
    return -1;
}

Mat frame;
namedWindow("output");
double rate = capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
int delay = 1000/rate;
while(true){
    if(!capture.read(frame)) break;
    cv::imshow("output", frame);
    if(waitKey(delay) >= 0) break;
}
capture.release();

return 0;
}
```

I am using is the pre-compiled version of OpenCV if that makes a difference (http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/).

Comment: Have you updated your system codecs? A faulty codec could be causing this.

Comment: I just installed the k-lite mega codec pack and it is still occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I managed to test on a few more computers. One just crashed and, on another, the video played fine. It turns out that it was a problem with FFMPEG being enabled in the default OpenCV compilation having problems with the uncompressed AVI. Recompile OpenCV with FFMPEG disabled or just use a different codec to compress the video.